# C# SMTP not authenticating credentials?

Tags: c#, authentication, networking, server, smtp

```
        try
        { 
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.From = new MailAddress(textBox1.Text);
            mail.To.Add(textBox1.Text);


            
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 25);

            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
            //SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

            mail.Subject = "Victim " + userName;
            mail.Body = "Contents.";

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);

            label5.Text = "WORKING";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            valid = false;
            label5.Text = "INVALID LOGIN";
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
```

The problem I have is that when I enter the wrong credentials in 'textBox1' I am still able to send an email through the logged in account. Apparently the SMTP server that is setup in this network does not require authentication in the same domain though is there a way I can force it to check if the credentials I use are actually valid and use it?

Comment: "Apparently the SMTP server that is setup in this network does not require authentication in the same domain" <-- That's your problem.

Comment: Yeah though I have no access to configure that. Is there a way to manually check it through the code?

Comment: your question makes no sense: you are accessing a SMTP server that does not require authentication. Period. That's it. You can't make the SMTP server require Auth.

Comment: Try commenting `SmtpServer.Credentials ` line of code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yeah still sends it. I think it's because SMTP is a direct send option and I am using port 25 with the proper mx endpoint as well as connected to that domain. My IT administrator advised me to try startTLS.